# Unable to add Stack Exchange login or change e-mail address

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I'm attempting to change the e-mail address used for Stack Exchange communications.  There doesn't seem to be an option for doing that, beyond creating a new StackExchange OpenID and merging the two accounts.  So in a different browser, I visited an SE site and created a new ID with the new e-mail address.  Then I went back to the primary browser where I was already logged in, and in My Logins I selected Add More Logins, clicked Log In with Stack Exchange, and entered credentials for the new account.

I got a warning like:

> This login is new to Stack Exchange (*my.new@email.address*) Do you want to add this login to your Stack Exchange account?

and I selected Add Login.

I then get an error:

> **Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:**
>
> **An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.**

This is pretty consistent.  After the first time, I no longer need to enter the credentials and am brought directly to the confirmation, always followed by the error.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't just trying to add a credential, but merge accounts since there was already an account that existed with that credential. For most people, this will still work. But there are certain criteria that will cause an automatic merge to fail.

The one catching you is that you have at least one profile that has >1,000 reputation on it, which is a criteria for failing the auto-merge. In a case like this, you just need to contact us in order to complete it.

I've gone ahead and merged the accounts together for you.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a strange and undocumented criteria, and not at all obvious from the error message given (especially since I have >20K rep on this account).